# Best way to insert an element into an ordered array in Scala

Tags: arrays, scala, sorting

I have an Array, or Seq looks like

```
val myArray = collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer[Int](1,4,8,10,12,13)

val newElem = 7
```

I want to insert the new element into the Array at the right position, so that the array is still ordered.

I don't want to generate a new array here.

My solution is to find the insert position first, and then insert it.

```
def findInsertPosition(myArray: collection.multable.ArrayBuffer[Int], newElem: Int): Int
```

then call

```
myArray.insert(pos, newElem)
```

The question is how to write the `findInsertPosition` function in Scala style, without using while, for loops?

or if you have better solution?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Find the insert position with `lastIndexWhere` and add one to it then `insert` at that position.

```
scala> val xs = scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer(1,4,8,10,12,13)
xs: scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer[Int] = ArrayBuffer(1, 4, 8, 10, 12, 13)

scala> xs.insert(xs.lastIndexWhere(_ < 7) + 1, 7)

scala> xs
res10: scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer[Int] = ArrayBuffer(1, 4, 7, 8, 10, 12, 13)
```

Comment: Thanks. Followup question: how to implement it if no lastIndexWhere function?

Comment: There may be other methods you could use from the standard library to accomplish the same thing. See the answers others have provided for examples. If you don't want to use a while loop and write something from scratch, I'd try a recursive function that takes `newElem` and `myArray` and returns an index you use to insert.

Answer (score 2):

This might be a bit inefficient, but it works:

```
def findInsertPosition(myArray: collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer[Int], newElem: Int): Int =
  myArray.takeWhile(_ < newElem).size
```

It will be the correct index when inserting.

Answer (score 2):

Find the correct index point and insert.

```
val idx = myArray.indexWhere(_>newElem)
myArray.insert(if (idx<0) myArray.length else idx, newElem)
// ArrayBuffer(1, 4, 7, 8, 10, 12, 13)
```

Answer (score 1):

The first thing that comes to my mind:

```
myArray.insert(
  Stream.range(0, myArray.length)
    .find(a(_) >= newElem)
    .getOrElse(myArray.length), 
  newElem)
```

another approach would be something similar to Brian's answer

```
myArray.insert(
  myArray.indexWhere(_ >= newElem),
  newElem)
```